# percentage input field treat 0 as null

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui

I have a percentage input field, whenever I entered 0 as input it display '' or null. How to get rid of it? I want to display 0 as it is, not just null value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give some details how are you implementing this percentage input field

Answer (score 0):

Check the link and open the stakblitz code for an example. You are missing [value]="percentage" most probably. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/numerictextbox/formats/

Comment: link is not working, I reload it many times but still not working

Comment: https://www.elite-corner.com/2018/11/angular-percent-pipe-example.html Check this if it works.

Comment: Can you paste your input tag code here or relevant code in comment for me to look at?

Comment: `<kendo-numerictextbox
                              [spinners]="false"
                              [format]="'p'"
                              [min]="0"
                            ></kendo-numerictextbox>`

Comment: i am using kendo ui for angular, and using 'p' as format is percentage

Comment: You are missing [value]="percentage"

Comment: @krlshnx Did the [value]="percentage" work? If you are still facing issue then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <kendo-numerictextbox
            [format]="'p'"
            [step]="0.1"
            [min]="0"
            [max]="1"
            [value]="percentage"
        ></kendo-numerictextbox>


 public percentage: number = 0.7;
```